# EOFerror on startup

Tags: python, startup, eof, eoferror

after loading script on startup I got a error EOFerror: 
Script is running in CLI mode.
EOF when reading a line.

> Barcode: Trace back (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/BCKHL.py",
>   line 48, in   compare() File "/home/pi/BCKHL.py", line 20, in
>   compare  barcode=input("barcode:")

Script is working when is running manually.

here is code for script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    ###setup###
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT) #Ventil 1#
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT) #Ventil 2#
GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT) #Ventil 1 crvena led#
GPIO.output(38, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT) #Ventil 1 zelena led#
GPIO.output(40, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.OUT) #Ventil 2 crvenaled#
GPIO.output(35, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT) #Ventil 2 zelena led lampa#
GPIO.output(37, GPIO.LOW)

def compare():
    while True:
        barcode=input("Barcode:")
        if barcode=="S5000070931":
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)            
            GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(38, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(35, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(37, GPIO.LOW)

            continue
        elif barcode=="S5000057670":
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(38, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(35, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(37, GPIO.HIGH)
            continue
        else:
            print("Molim Vas da skenirate ispravan barkod")
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(38, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(35, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(37, GPIO.LOW)
            continue

compare()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't seem to habe an inactive terminal. How did you start it?

Comment: I tried this method: systemd. From this link https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup#method-3-systemd

Comment: ``input`` asks for input via ``stdin``. This is not meaningful for a system service, since there is no-one to provide that input.

Comment: I tried with: import sys, barcode=sys.stdin.read("Barcode:")
But I i got error "integer argument expected, got 'str'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it from .bashrc

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
```

on last line write:

```
echo Running at boot 
sudo python3 /home/pi/BCKHL.py
```

And dont forget to remove it from rc.local if u still have it there.